# "What" or "Which"?

Tags: questions

Suppose I am a book shop keeper  and someone comes to my shop and he's looking here and there in my shop. Should I ask him:

> **What** book are you looking for?

or

> **Which** book are you looking for?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37325/which-vs-what-usage. Related from other site: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/3413/91730

Comment: Could you possibly improve your question, please? bookshop owner, not keeper. Clue: in English: to look ***for***. What book are you looking for?

Comment: @Lambie - you never heard of a shopkeeper? "bookshop keeper" gets 29000 hits on [google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rls=com.microsoft%3Aen-GB%3AIE-Address&q=%22bookshop+keeper%22&oq=%22bookshop+keeper%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30k1j0i8i7i10i30k1j0i8i30k1.4217.4217.0.4839.1.1.0.0.0.0.63.63.1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.63.V_KuIdXJE_A). It may not be perfectly idiomatic but it's good enough for me.

Comment: @AndyT Of course, a shopkeeper and a bookshop owner, but not a bookshop keeper. It just ain't kosher.

Comment: Both "what" and "which" are fine, which you use is entirely up to you.  in this context there is no difference in meaning.

Comment: @Andrew - I'd be more likely to use _what_ if the customer looked like they weren't sure what they wanted, and _which_ if the customer was, say, carrying a list with four books listed, and three books under his arm. That said, if there's any difference at all, I'd agree that it's minimal if not negligible.

Answer (score 1):

To some extent this is entirely personal preference.  As J.R. mentions in his comment,  you may be more likely to use "what" if the customer isn't sure what kind of book is wanted, and "which" if the customer has some kind of more specific list.

However, many native speakers will use these interchangeably, without really thinking about which/what would be more appropriate.  The meaning is almost exactly the same either way, at least in the given context.

As a side note:  I agree with Lambie that "book shop keeper" sounds a little odd to this American.  It might be more of a British English expression.  I would be more inclined to say *"the owner/manager of a bookshop"*