# What do you like to eat – fish or meat?

Tags: questions

As I know it, if we have small number of possibilities, we choose "which", not "what". But in the following sentence, perhaps, is it possible to ask in that way? If you have more idiomatic ways to ask it, please write them.

> What do you like to eat – fish or meat?

Comment: You know that we do not correct text here. You are supposed to say or explain why you think it's right or wrong first.

Comment: Now, is it OK ?

Comment: Somewhat better. I didn't even realize you were asking about which versus what here.

Comment: This might help [which versus what usage](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/37325/9161)

Comment: [Does it sounds good? Get it? Present simple. You should already know this. Is it sounds good=buzzer].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- What do you like to eat? Fish or meat or vegetables?

I like fish. Fish = direct object

- Which *would you like to eat*? Fish or meat?

I'd like to eat fish.

Either can be used, they mean something a little different.

Which implies a choice.

Comment: Which implies a choice between a limited number of choices, defined in the question or shortly before. What implies a choice between an unknown or unlimited number of choices, not specified.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Which, when there are two choices only, as here, implies a choice between two things.

Comment: Is it possible to ask "Which do you like to eat – fish or meat?" or it sounds bad?

Comment: @Sergey You know the rule for **habitual** action. It's simple present. But, not if you are inviting someone or inquiring politely as some particular present time. This:   Which or what food **do you like** to eat? Sounds like a survey question or that you are asking about a person's habits. But it does not sound like you sitting in a restaurant deciding what to eat. That is with WOULD.

Comment: OK, I have understood it.